# Why does the startup time grow when we group forced reflows using fastdom?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

We're building a web framework and have identified [forced reflows](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) as one of the main performance bottlenecks of our applications. From web research, we learned that actions that trigger forced reflows should be grouped into read- and write-batches to minimize the number of reads that actually are costly (because something changed). [Our main goal is to get rid of forced reflows altogether, but we doubt that we can remove every single one – and from what we learned it is the first one after a change that is expensive.]

In a proof of concept, we implemented this batch approach using the [fastdom](https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom) library for a single application start. Surprisingly, instead of the performance increase, we hoped for, the startup performance decreased from (in median) 372ms to 391ms time to interactive. In the performance trace, we see that the large recalculate style/layout cycle now directly comes from revealing the changed HTML, and that the js-triggered forced reflows (in the animation frame after that reveal) are actually fast. However, the overall performance was better with the forced reflows happening before the reveal.

*performance trace before implementing fastdom:*
[image: performance trace before implementing fastdom]

*performance trace after implementing fastdom:*
[image: performance trace after implementing fastdom]

**Can someone explain why we observe this behavior?** Why does it seem that the community-approved approach works in the opposite direction in our case?

Thanks for all hints in advance!

Comment: What did you do in that application start? It seems that the fastdom is to be used for some repetitive dom related tasks like as animations..

Comment: We render a near-empty shell and request the actual html for the specific application in a 2nd roundtrip. The trace screenshots show only the response to this 2nd roundtrip. Yeah, fastdom seems to be targeted at animations, and we mainly adjust the height/width of elements based on the current surroundings (i.e. sth like `element.style.width = element.parentElement.offsetWidth + 'px'`), but this causes forced reflows as well.